# Controlling the "add a keyword for this search" context menu entry

Tags: html, firefox, html-input

I'd like to suppress Firefox's "Add a Keyword for this Search" context-menu (right-click) item which appears (inappropriately) on certain `input` elements, e.g.:

```
<form method="post">
  <!-- the following will have an inappropriate context-menu entry -->
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```

As far as I've been able to tell, the context menu entry appears by default on any `input` inside a `form`. It appears on any "text-ish" input type, including `text`, `number`, `tel`, `email`, and (of course) `search`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bF9ws/)

I'm in ASP.NET so I can't remove the form or change its `method`. Any other options are OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` element, then Firefox will not include "Add a Keyword" in the context menu:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```

This is due to a limitation in Firefox; see [this code](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/879038dcacb7/browser/base/content/nsContextMenu.js#l1513) for details.  If this limitation is fixed, this workaround might stop working in future versions of Firefox.

The "Add a Keyword for this Search" menu item is a standard feature of Firefox, and might even be useful to some of your users in some cases, so I would also recommend just ignoring it if it's not actively harming your site.

Comment: That's great. I'll consider submitting a bug to make this only the default on `search` inputs. The `input`s in my case are things like "shipping address", so the keyword search really would be inappropriate.